# How to pass an array as html input and pass it to php for printing?

Tags: php, html

I am wondering how to take an html form input as an array (list of floating point numbers, real numbers, with a max character limit of 50) and pass that data to a php variable so I can manipulate it and display it in a text document. Here is what I have for inputs, the trouble is the last one that I need as an array:

```
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="UpdateInfo.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold"> User Info</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>First Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="fname" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Max 20 Characters, only A-Z or a-z"  maxlength = 20 /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="lname" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Max 20 Characters, only A-Z or a-z"  maxlength = 20  /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>ID Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="id" required pattern=[a-z]{3}[1-9]{3} title="Must be abc123 format!" maxlength="6" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>List of values: </td><td><input type="text" name="listOfValues" maxlength="50" />
</tr>
```

and my form data is:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") //post request w/o post data
{
$fname = $_POST['fname']; //sets new variables = to our post data inputs
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$userID=$_POST['id'];
$valuesList=$_POST['listOfValues'];
```

Again, I want this listOfValues to be an array comma seperated list of decimal and whole numbers to sort through.

Comment: What isn't working?  If you type `1,2.0,3.3,4,13` into that input the you'll get it in PHP.  Then just `explode(',', $_POST['listOfValues'])` if you want an array.

Comment: I assume you just didn't paste the required html tags and closing /form tag...

Comment: @AbraCadaver I got that to work, is there any way to use fwrite() to write the whole array into a text file? If not, do you know any other ways to do it?

Comment: You want to write out the array or the comma separated list? If the array then `json_encode` and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php